# Objective-C memory management: if I release a string stored in an array, it only releases this reference or it releases the object in the array?

Tags: objective-c, memory-management

If I have this:

```
NSString *lastPushed = (NSString *)[tagStack objectAtIndex:[tagStack count]-1];
.//do something with the last pushed element locally
.//do more cstuff here
.//after doing all the stuff needed in the function

[lastPushed release];
```

where tagStack is an NSMutableArray

If I release lastPushed, since it was not copied, or inited, will it only release this reference or will it actually release the object in the mutableArray?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You didn't `alloc`, `new`, or `copy` or `mutableCopy` `lastPushed`, so why are you releasing it?

Since `lastPushed` is a pointer to the object in the array, you are releasing that. This *could* lead to a problem when your array thinks that it has a valid pointer to an object but you've released it and it's been `dealloc`ed.

Answer (score 4):

It will release the object in the array because both `lastPushed` and the array point to *the same object*.

As always, you should follow the management rules. Do not release anything that you have not created, retained or copied.

Comment: I'd like to add that in your own functions that are not named "new", "copy" or "alloc", you should also return an object not created by these functions. If you do, make sure you first call [returnedObject autorelease]; -- this is what Apple's functions do.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't be releasing lastPushed, as you didn't use `alloc`, `copy` or `new`. (It's that simple.)

If you want to remove it from the mutable array, you should use the appropriate method in the [NSMutableArray](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html) (`removeObject` or `removeObjectAtIndex`, etc.) Otherwise, it's unclear what you're trying to do which will bite you next week/month/year, etc.